# C# Creating Zip with multiple Word Docs inside

Tags: c#, file, download, stream, zip

Currently stuck with a corrupt .zip folder which contains what I believe to be the right contents (size increases as I include more word doc's).

Not sure why it's corrupting the zip - it generates the word document soundly, as that was my previous implementation and that hasn't changed.

```
private void GenReport(List<PerformanceReport> performanceReportData2, string start, string end)
        {
            List<byte[]> byteList = new List<byte[]>();

            var document = Server.MapPath("~/Content/docs/Performance Report.docx");
            var byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(document);

            // Format parameters
            var startRange = DateTime.Parse(start);
            var endRange = DateTime.Parse(end);
            foreach (var performanceReportData in performanceReportData2)
            {
                var trust = performanceReportData.Name.Replace(",", string.Empty);
                trust = trust.Replace("&", string.Empty);
                start = start.Replace("/", "-");
                end = end.Replace("/", "-");

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
                    {
                        var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                        ....... Do stuff
                        body.Document.Save();
                        byteList.Add(stream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (var attachment in byteList)
                    {
                        var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("test.docx");

                        using (var originalFile = new MemoryStream(attachment))
                        {
                            using (var zipEntryStream = entry.Open())
                            {
                                originalFile.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Performance Report.zip");
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    ms.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

I've run out of ideas as to why it would corrupt the Zip folder - if I open the zip folder in a text editor, it begins with PK which I gather confirms it is a Zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the scopes incorrect.

The working code looks like this

```
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (var attachment in byteList)
                    {
                        var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(attachment.Key);

                        using (var originalFile = new MemoryStream(attachment.Value))
                        {
                            using (var zipEntryStream = entry.Open())
                            {
                                originalFile.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Reports.zip");
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ms.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.End();
```